# How to prove the fairness of AIMD in TCP?

Tags: tcp, congestion-control

I am currently studying the Additive Increase Multiplicative Decrease method, used in TCP as congestion avoidance technique.  If we have K TCP sessions sharing a common link of bandwidth R, it is said that this technique guarantees fairness for all the sessions, i.e, each session will have a throughput of R/K.

Now, I'd like to prove this fairness mathematically (reaching the conclusion that, regardless of the initial values of the throughput of each session, they will all eventually tend to R/K).

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

A very intuitive answer is illustrated [in the Chiu-Jain paper](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~ravenben/classes/papers/cj89.pdf). From there, you can easily see a sort of general argument for AIMD that can be formalized further.  All you really need is in that paper.

If you insist on proof by letters rather than proof by graph, you can reason as follows:

Assume `x, y` are the initial shares of the bandwidth, which is `R`. Let `2d = R` for convenience.

The sequence of window size ratios evolves like follows:

```
(init) x/y -> 
(MD) (x/2)/(y/2) = x/y -> 
(AI) (x + d)/(y + d) -> 
(MD) ((x + d)/2)/((y + d)/2) -> 
(AI) ((x + d)/2 + d) / ((y + d) /2 + d) = (x + d + 2d)/(y + d + 2d)
```

This last one is `(x + d + 2d)/(y + d + 2d)`. And you can see if you write it down how it is going to evolve after that.

In general,  `(x + k /y + k) -> 1` as `k` grows, and in our specific case the convergence is even exponential because k grows exponentially with time. This is what the convergence to fairness looks [like](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427el6p6t4tel9) for a starting point of `x = 5` and `y = 3`.

To prove it for more than 2 flows you can take the flows with largest and smallest starting share of the bandwidth. Everyone else is in between, so the proof should still be simple.  The convergence we talk about here is convergence to fairness,  not convergence to `R/K` because in reality the system will oscillate between `R/2K` and `R/K` forever.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting scholarly level feedback, I recommend searching scholar.google.com. The one entitled [A Note on the Fairness of Additive Increase and Multiplicative Decrease](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/52292/files/IC_TECH_REPORT_199833.pdf) with fancy looking maths might be right up your alley.